# AJAX doesn't update value of a text box

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to update a value of a input text box via AJAX. I cannot make it work althouth almost the same AJAX code works fine for 'text' only. The same behavior for ff & chrome.

the only difference is

```
doesn't work ---> document.getElementById("f1").value=revision;  
works fine -----> document.getElementById("f2").innerHTML=revision;
works fine too -> onClick="javascript:document.getElementById('f1').value+='B';"
```

sample code:

```
<input type="text" name="f1" id="f1"> 
<input type="button" value="inline function"  onClick="javascript:document.getElementById('f1').value+='B';">
<input type="button" value="AJAX Button" onClick="get_revision2('trunk')">
```

and the function

```
    function get_revision2(revision)
    {
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
      else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        document.getElementById("f1").value=revision;

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
          document.getElementById("f1").value=xmlhttp.responseText;

          }
        }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","http://radek:4567/svn_get_revision?code_base="+revision+"&t=" + Math.random(),true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

the AJAX code doesn't update the value of the text box. The inline function does.

But for text (not the input text box) even AJAX works fine.

```
<DIV id="f2">revision</div>
<input type="button" value="inline function" onClick="javascript:document.getElementById('f2').innerHTML+='B';">
<input type="button" value="AJAX" onClick="get_revision3('3.0')">
```

and the function

```
    function get_revision3(revision)
    {
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
      else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        document.getElementById("f2").innerHTML=revision;

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
          document.getElementById("f2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

          }
        }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","http://radek:4567/svn_get_revision?code_base="+revision+"&t=" + Math.random(),true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Comment: The simplest explanation is that the AJAX request is failing. Try adding an alert if the xmlhttp.status is not 200

Comment: @Hans: the AJAX call works if updating text. And in the case where the text box value is not updated 'radek' server receives the AJAX call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the JavaScript console for errors? Is it possible you are getting an Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when the script is executing the AJAX call?

If the web page you are running the XMLHttpRequest from is not on the same domain as the URL of the AJAX request then the browser is stopping the request. Cross-site HTTP requests are restricted.

Comment: the web page is from server 'testing' and AJAX request is to server 'radek'. Above I described that AJAX call works that way if updating text using '.innerHTML' It doesn't work if updating using '.value'

Comment: I am getting no error but let me explore more the cross-site requests. It looks that this is the reason ...

Comment: Have checked the error console. It should specify an error based on restrictions.

Comment: I made AJAX call to web page server where I made another call to radek server and everything works fine now. THank you. So It must be the cross-site request. Actually the request was made but probably the result was not accepted.... IMHO

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to reproduce your error. Check out http://jsbin.com/ahusa4/3/edit

Are you sure you don't have another element with id "f1"? maybe the common: `<form id='f1' name='f1'>`

Comment: the error is that the text box is not updated with the result of AJAX call. There should be a number. The string 'trunk' is the AJAX call parameter. It cannot work for you because you don't have the server radek up and running. BUT my other example where AJAX call is updating text field WORKS. So the questions is why it doesn't work for value of a text box...